# Magento 2.x: add column to sales order history page (FO)

Tags: magento2, grid, frontend

What are methods for add a column to sales_order_history page? without edite

```
view/frontend/templates/order/history.phtml
```

can help me please ?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to touch view/frontend/templates/order/history.phtml template file to add aditional column into customer sales order history page.

copy layout view/frontend/layout/sales_order_history.xml to your theme and add addtional column header to sales.order.history.extra.column.header block and render column data using sales.order.history.extra.container block.

The solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <!-- This will add additional column header to order list -->
        <referenceBlock name="sales.order.history.extra.column.header">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="your.additional.column.header" template="Namespace_Module::columnheader.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>

        <!-- You can access current order using $this->getOrder() inside the template "-->
        <referenceBlock name="sales.order.history.extra.container">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="your.additional.column.data" template="Namespace_Module::columndata.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: I was able to add the column header like you suggest but I can't determine how to populate the column. Can you please expand on how you implemented the columndata.phtml?

Comment: Nevermind I was able to figure it out.

Comment: <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Date')) ?>" class="col date">
<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getOrder()->getCreatedAt()) ?>
</td>

I have added into columndata.phtml file to display Date.

Answer (score 4):

In Magento 2.3.3

app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/sales_order_history.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <!-- This will add additional column header to order list -->
    <referenceBlock name="sales.order.history.extra.column.header">
        <block name="vendor.additional.column.header" template="Vendor_Module::history-header.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>

    <!-- You can access current order using $this->getOrder() inside the template "-->
    <referenceBlock name="sales.order.history.extra.container">
        <block name="vendor.additional.column.data" template="Vendor_Module::history.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/history.phtml

```
<?php
    /* @var $block \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\History\Container */
?>

 <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Created At')) ?>" class="col created- 
 date">
  <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getOrder()->getCreatedAt()) ?>
  </td>
```

app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/history-header.phtml

```
<?php
  /* @var $block \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\History\Container */
 ?>
    <th data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Created At')) ?>" class="col created-date">
    <?= $block->escapeHtml("Created At") ?>
 </th>
```

Answer (score 2):

> create the 'sales_order_history.xml' into your theme **(view\frontend\layout\sales_order_history.xml)** or your module **(Magento_Sales\layout\sales_order_history.xml)**

add the following content in **sales_order_history.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="sales.order.history.extra.container" template="Vendor_Module::OrderHistoryColumn.phtml"/>
</body>
```

> create the **OrderHistoryColumn.phtml** file and add content. I have
>   added the created column into the History

```
<?php
/* @var $block \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\History\Container */
?>

<td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Created At')) ?>" class="col date">
    <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getOrder()->getCreatedAt()) ?>
</td>
```

run the following commands

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:di:compile
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
>
> php bin/magento indexer:reindex
>
> php bin/magento cache:clean

Check the output.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you need to edit sales order history template, without edit its not possible. The sales order history grid container being managed via

> vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/order/history.phtml

You can override this template in your custom theme at:

> app/design/frontend/Your/theme/Magento_Sales/templates/order/history.phtml

add the required column and get value for the same.

**Update**

Yes, we can use `$block->getChildHtml('extra.column.header');` to add new column to sales order history. If you look into that template, there is code

```
<?php echo $block->getChildHtml('extra.column.header');?>
```

to add additional columns and value being populated by

```
<?php if ($extra): ?>
       <?php $extra->setOrder($_order); ?>
       <?php /* @noEscape */ echo $extra->getChildHtml() ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Also it is referenced in sales_order_history.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\History" name="sales.order.history" cacheable="false">
                <container name="sales.order.history.info" as="info" label="Order History Info"/>
                <container name="sales.order.history.extra.column.header" as="extra.column.header" label="Order History Extra Column Header"/>
                <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\History\Container"
                       name="sales.order.history.extra.container" as="extra.container">
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
                        name="sales.order.history.extra.container.data" as="extra.container.data"/>
                </block>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard" name="customer.account.link.back" template="account/link/back.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
        </referenceContainer>
```

However, I am not sure where we need to add extra columns. I checked store configuration but can't see the option to add new columns to order history. I am also curious to know more about it, will update you if get more idea on it. Please update me too in case you get anything on it :)

Comment: the detail extra.column.header "$block->getChildHtml('extra.column.header')" it's for add a column without modified the template .phtml,  the probleme is exist in exam certification Magento 2 professional developer

Comment: Yes, it could also be used but that column would be shown at the end but you need your column after "Ship to" I hope. I am not sure if you will be able to adjust column at required location using $block->getChildHtml('extra.column.header')

Comment: add the column befor or after "Ship to" it's no problem, but really it's a question exists in exam certified Magento professionnel developer.

Comment: I failed the first time I tried to pass the certification, I worked on memorizing the questions, the way they were formulated and the points I was not sure about.

Comment: Oh I see! I am also preparing for the same. Best of the luck for next time (Y)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to touch view/frontend/templates/order/history.phtml template file to add aditional column into customer sales order history page.

copy layout view/frontend/layout/sales_order_history.xml to your theme and add addtional column header to sales.order.history.extra.column.header block and render column data using sales.order.history.extra.container block.

You have all set now.